# Bind Exclude still binding parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was hoping to understand the behavior of Bind Exclude in the following situation:

Here is my model class:

```
public class Client  
{   

        [Required]
        public int? ClientId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Post method in my controller:

```
public int PostClient([Bind(Exclude = "ClientId")]Client client)
```

Using fiddler, I send ClientId and Name in the Json string. When I debug PostClient, I see that the client.ClientId is set to the value I send through fiddler. But because I have used ClientId in the bind exclude category, I expected null or default value for ClientId. Can somebody help me understand why the value is set for ClientId?

PS: I understand that ViewModels work better in this case - creating a new model class only with the parameters I want to bind. Although I might go with that, this question is only to understand Bind Exclude well.

Comment: That should have worked. Sanity check - have you verified that it is correct version of DLL that your app is running?

Comment: This code works as is. I tested it.

Comment: Wow, this is annoying. Thanks Yogiraj for your confirmation. It's possible I am missing something silly in my App, but I am still facing the issue. The Json string I pass is "{"ClientId":1021,"Name":"test10"}". When I debug, I see client.ClientId as 1021 in PostClient.

Comment: @Anirudh Without looking at your app code, it will be hard to determine what is going on. Have you tried creating a viewModel?

Comment: Ofcourse, View model works - as I would have expected.